# Regex to match last single quote that is really single

Tags: regex

What is regex to match the last single quote in a string that is really single ( i mean it does not have any partner back) so we should get last quote in the:

```
foo('bar').baz("foo'foo").bar('baz').foo('bar
```

but nothing to match in the following:

```
foo('bar').baz
```

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) What are you trying to make with this?

Comment: XY problem? i dont think so. the question is clear. If someone ask you what is the regex to match single-quotes you answer ' . and whats is the last single-quote: answer '[^']*$. now i also want to check if thats single or not maybe catch it in a catching group and then look-back. is it possible with regexes or i should write a function to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is quite a complex task, especially since you're involving double quotes. But you might make it work with something like this:

```
^('[^']*'|"[^"]*"|[^'"])*$
```

From the start of the string, it matches either

- a single quoted string
- a double quoted string
- or a character **not** being a single or double quote

Then it goes on 'til the end of the string. If it encounters unbalanced quotes, it fails.

I'm pretty sure this will fail in *many* cases, but the simplest ones should work.

[Check it out at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/cG6cB1/3).

**Edit:** In the example I had to put newline - `\n` - in negated classes as well to illustrate several examples.